# ASP MVC4 await with httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm learning how to use Tasks in MVC and I get completly lost. I need to download the source from selected webpage, find one element, get its value and return it. That's it.
For this I am using HtmlAgilityPack and HttpClient to fetch the webpage.
The problem that occurs is where nothing is waiting for response from httpClient and thus results that response generation completed when Task was still in progress. (**An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.**)

I read lots of threads in here ,codeproj and some blogs, still don't understand what's the problem. Most common explanation is about resulting type of void in async method, but I cannot find any other way to return awaiting value, than this:

```
public float ReadPrice(Uri url)
{
    switch (url.Host)
    {
       case "www.host1.xy":
            return ParseXYZAsync(url).Result;
       default:
            return float.Parse("99999,99");
    }
}

private Task<float> ParseXYZAsync(Uri url)
{
    loadPage(url);

    var priceNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
        @"//*[@id='pageWrapper']/div[4]/section[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/span");
    var price = priceNode.InnerText;
     ...
    return priceInFloat;
}

private async Task LoadPage(Uri url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

    String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                            .GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);

    document.LoadHtml(source);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to figure out what's wrong you need to understand one key concept with async-await. When an async method hits the first `await` keyword, control is yielded back to the calling method. This means that when you do this:

```
loadPage(url);
```

The method will synchronously run until it hits:

```
var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
```

Which will yields control back to `ParseWebSite`, which will continue execution and will probably end before the async operation has actually completed.

What you need to do is make `LoadPage` return a `Task` and `await` for it's completion:

```
private async Task<float> ParseWebsiteAsync(Uri url)
{
    await LoadPageAsync(url);

    var priceNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode
        (@"//*[@id='pageWrapper']/div[4]/section[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/span");
    var price = priceNode.InnerText;
    return priceInFloat;
}

private async Task LoadPageAsync(Uri url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var source = await http.GetAsStringAsync(url);

    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
    document.LoadHtml(source);
}
```

**Side Notes:**

1. Do follow .NET naming conventions. Methods should be PascalCase and not camelCase
2. Do add the "Async" postfix for asynchronous methods. E.g, `LoadPage` should become `LoadPageAsync`.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer, it explains a lot. Does it mean that for just fetching a webpage I will need two tasks? That's why there are so many of them in the OS, when simple things needs more than one.

Comment: @Vilo You'll need as many tasks as the number of method calls you'll be making, because async goes "all the way", from the top to the bottom of your call stack.

Comment: I found another issue, something from standard synchronous flow is calling this ParseWebsiteAsync() method, when I've changed the return type to Task<float> It says that it cannot convert Task<float> to float. I need this method (which contains a switch() ) to be synchronous. Adding async to this method will yield need to add async to one above and another and another until I hit a controller which will continue to create lots of different tasks. What is good solution for this puropse? I need ParseWebsiteAsync to return a float (or the parent method).

Comment: @Vilo At the top calling method to your question, so I can see what it looks like

Comment: Okay, I've edited the top post with your changes, also I've added to the calling method in switch-case to return the Task Result. What happens now is that the answer is never comming - application freezes for long time, on fiddler I can see the response came back.

Comment: @Vilo That's because you shouldn't block on async code, it's causing your code to deadlock. Make `ReadPrice` return `Task<float>` and use `return await ParseXYZAsync;` instead of `return ParseXYZAsync.Result`.

Comment: Then another method which is calling ReadPrice will need to be async and have await, then another one will have this need etcetera etcetera, how to avoid it and finally get the result, not task?

Comment: @Vilo That's what I previously told you, and I didn't lie. Async indeed goes all the way. This means it will go all the way up to your MVC controller action, which will be async as well.

Comment: So I understood you wrong before, okay - thank you for patience, now it's time for me to fight with that.

Answer (score 1):

private async void loadPage(Uri url) needs to return a Task:

```
private async Task loadPage(Uri url)
```

then you need to await it in the calling method:

```
private async Task<float> parseWEBSITEXY(Uri url)
{
 await loadPage(url);
...
}
```

In you code load page starts and it returns immediately.
One more thing - it is not recommended to use async void, except for event handlers. Always return Task.